# creating instance methods outside of the constructor in python

Tags: python, oop, constructor, beautifulsoup

I am able to get my code to work, but I am wondering if it is correct to set an instance method on a class outside of the constructor.  When I wrote this, it just didn't feel right but I couldn't figure out a way to do it within the constructor.  Any help on how to refactor this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
class Parser():

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri

    def createSoup(self):
        htmlPage = urlopen(self.uri)
        htmlText = htmlPage.read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)

def main():
    urls = Url().return_urls()
    p = Parser(urls[test])
    p.createSoup()
    print(p.soup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I thought would be better, but I couldn't get it to work was to set self.soup in the constructor like so:

```
def __init__(self, uri):
    self.uri = uri
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
```

Comment: That's not a method, it's an attribute.  Also, in what way did it not work when you tried to do it in `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help you?. Call createSoup function inside init.

```
class Parser():

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri
        self.soup = self.createSoup()

    def createSoup(self):
        htmlPage = urlopen(self.uri)
        htmlText = htmlPage.read()
        return BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
```

Other way is to create BeautifulSoup instance in main() method and send it as parameter to Parser as Parser(urls[test], BeautifulSoup_instance) and assign it to self.soup in init() function.